# Find $q$ and $r$ with $0\leq r\leq |b|$, such that $a=qb+r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find $q$ and $r$, with $0\leq r\leq |b|$, such that $a=qb+r$ for
>
> - $a=115,\ b=26$
> - $a=400,\ b=-17$
> - $a=-312,\ b=-64$

Sadly I missed the class where the prof went over this, so I have no idea what to do. Can somebody point me in the direction of the name of a process or theorem or something so that I can find out how to do it?

Thanks..

Comment: Hmmm. I understand how the Euclidean algorithm works for finding relative primality and the GCD of two numbers... Is this similar? It didn't appear to be when I first read it.

Comment: Yes. Very similar. This is a single iteration in Euclid's algorithm for findsing the gcd.

Comment: This is the [integer division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) with quotient $\rm\,q\,$ and remainder $\rm\,r.\:$ Yes, the division algorithm is the inductive step in the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have dealt with the case when $a \ge 0$ and $b > 0$ in school.

When $a < 0$ and $b > 0$ divide first $-a$ by $b$
$$
-a = b q + r, \qquad 0 \le r < b,
$$
then consider
$$
a = b (-q) -r
$$
If $r = 0$, then you're done. If $0 < r < b$, then
$$
a = b (-q -1) + b - r, \qquad 0 < b - r < b.
$$
Finally, if $b < 0$, divide $a$ by $-b$
$$
a = (-b) q + r = b (-q) + r, \qquad 0 \le r < -b = \vert b \rvert,
$$
done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $(q_0,r_0)$ is the solution to $a=qb+r$ then $(q_0-k,r_0)$ is the solution to $a-kb = qb+r$. In fact $q = \frac{a-r}{b}$ and because $0\leq r < |b|$ we have $0\leq\left|\frac{a}{b}-q\right|<1$.

Good luck ;-)